# What is the first television show with a trans male lead?

Tags: first-appearance

I've been telling people that that the first two television shows with trans male leads came out this month, either Dead End: Paranormal Park (Netflix, 16 June 2022) or The Umbrella Academy (Netflix, February 15 2019, but Viktor was not established as trans until 22 June 2022), but I'm wondering if that's actually true.

For the purposes of this question:

- The lead character (not necessarily the actor) of the show must be canonically established as trans male. I'm considering the lead to be the character with the most screentime played by the actor with first billing. So, a season regular character played by a junior actor in an ensemble wouldn't count, and a show where an actress plays a male clone/alternate timeline version of her character for a single episode wouldn't either.
- The show must have originally aired as a television show, not a movie chopped into parts. (So the 2020 movie Rurangi doesn't count, even though it is available on Hulu as a mini-series.)
- The show must air on cable, broadcast television, or a mainstream streaming service (not YouTube or a niche platform for queer indie projects).

Comment: [Wikipedia - List of transgender characters in television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transgender_characters_in_television)

Comment: Your asking for the first case of the actor being a trans male, not the character, right? As in, if a trans male character is played by a cis male actor, that would not answer the question?

Comment: Whichever one of these is the earliest might be the answer: https://www.out.com/television/2021/9/03/12-tv-shows-trans-men-characters-played-trans-actors#media-gallery-media-11

Comment: Can you clarify “lead”? Does any recurring opening credits role count? Or does it have to be a character with generally the most screen time?

Comment: None of the characters in the Out article are leads. I checked all the trans male characters in the current Wikipedia list and The Umbrella Academy is currently the earliest with a trans male lead, but I don't know if that list is comprehensive or accurate (sometimes Wikipedia incorrectly uses trans man to mean trans woman and visa versa)

Comment: Does it need to be live-action and in the English language?  Or does [Wandering Son](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2011519/) (2011) count?  It may also be disqualified because it appears to have two lead characters—a trans girl and a trans boy—rather than a single trans male lead.  (I haven't watched the show, so my description may be inaccurate.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert , that's definitely a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Wandering Son* (放浪息子, Hōrō Musuko)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/8426/Hourou_Musuko) was a one-season anime series that aired in 2011.  It features two protagonists, one a trans girl and one a trans boy.  A synopsis from the above link:

> Effeminate fifth grader Shuuichi Nitori is considered by most to be one of the prettiest girls in school, but much to her dismay, she is actually biologically male. Fortunately, Shuuichi has a childhood friend who has similar feelings of discomfort related to gender identity: **the lanky tomboy Yoshino Takatsuki, who, though biologically female, does not identify as a girl.** These two friends share a similar secret and find solace in one another; however, their lives become even more complicated when they must tread the unfamiliar waters of a new school, attempt to make new friends, and struggle to maintain old ones. Faced with nearly insurmountable odds, they must learn to deal with the harsh realities of growing up, transexuality, relationships, and acceptance.

I should note that I have not watched this show, and so I cannot speak to the accuracy of the descriptions.  In particular, it is not clear to me whether the two protagonists are equal co-leads or whether Shuuichi is more properly viewed as the main character of the show;  if the latter, it might not be the best example of what the OP is looking for.